# PostgreSQL: Constraint no duplicate cell in row

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've got a table `lineup`.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS lineup (
  match_id    INTEGER REFERENCES matches,
  pos_1       INTEGER REFERENCES players,
  pos_2       INTEGER REFERENCES players,
  pos_3       INTEGER REFERENCES players,
  pos_4       INTEGER REFERENCES players,
  pos_5       INTEGER REFERENCES players,
  pos_6       INTEGER REFERENCES players
);
```

It's for storing the lineup for a volleyball match. You've got six positions on the field. Each position must have a player. However all player IDs must be different. A player cannot be on multiple positions at the same time. How can I model this using a constraint?

```
match_id, pos_1, pos_2, pos_3, pos_4, pos_5, pos_6
1, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 // ok
1, 10, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15 // not ok, pos_1 == pos_2
1, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 10 // not ok, pos_1 == pos_6
1, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 14 // not ok, pos_5 == pos_6
```

I thought about something like

```
CONSTRAINT no_duplicate_players CHECK (pos_1 != pos_2 AND pos_1 != pos_3 ... AND pos_5 != pos_6)
```

That will be quite a long constraint and I'm wondering if there's something simpler.

Thanks,
Mirco

Comment: If your goal is to ensure referential integrity, I'd suggest normalizing the structure further (e.g. `match_id`, `position_id`, `player_id`). You could then present the data in the format you've got it in the table as a view.

Comment: maybe in constraint `IN CLAUSE` might work can try `NOT IN (pos1,pos2,..)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this effectively is to further normalize the table by normalizing the position column.

### Normalized Table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS lineup (
    match_id    INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES matches,
    position_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES positions,
    player_id   INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES players
    CONSTRAINT lineups_pk PRIMARY KEY (match_id, position_id, player_id)
);
```

### Positions Table

You'd also need a positions table, something like:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS positions (
    position_id INTEGER,
    position TEXT, -- or whatever your character type of choice is
    CONSTRAINT positions_pk PRIMARY KEY (position_id)
);
```

---

This approach has the advantage of enforcing the constraint you're looking to enforce, and the added benefit that it's flexible in the future if you determine you need to add more information about the positions, the players, or the matches.

### Viewing the Data

You can then present the data in your desired format by doing something like this:

```
SELECT
      match_id
    , a.player_id AS pos_1
    , b.player_id AS pos_2
    , c.player_id AS pos_3
    , d.player_id AS pos_4
    , e.player_id AS pos_5
    , f.player_id AS pos_6
FROM (SELECT match_id, player_id FROM lineup WHERE position_id = 1) a
LEFT JOIN (SELECT match_id, player_id FROM lineup WHERE position_id = 2) b USING (match_id)
LEFT JOIN (SELECT match_id, player_id FROM lineup WHERE position_id = 3) c USING (match_id)
LEFT JOIN (SELECT match_id, player_id FROM lineup WHERE position_id = 4) d USING (match_id)
LEFT JOIN (SELECT match_id, player_id FROM lineup WHERE position_id = 5) e USING (match_id)
LEFT JOIN (SELECT match_id, player_id FROM lineup WHERE position_id = 6) f USING (match_id);
```

It's a bit more work to set it up this way, but once you've got the query you can create it as a view, and then you've always got it, and you've benefited from the additional normalization. This way also makes it easier to answer questions like, "in how many matches did player_id 1 play?" and "are they always playing in the same position?"

---

### Ensuring All Six Positions Filled

Originally, this answer missed the requirement that we need to ensure that all six positions are filled. With no additions, this ensures that every position *enumerated* is filled, but allows for the possibility that a position wouldn't be inserted. There are two ways to approach this issue:

- Ensure on insert **via application / insert technique**

  - Pros: faster, lighter
  - Cons: doesn't enforce at database level, possible to having missingness in the data
- Ensure on insert / delete **via database trigger**

  - Pros: enforces at database level, making it impossible (if implemented correctly) to have missingness
  - Cons: here be triggers

DBA StackExchange has a great [question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/23475/113483) and [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/23522/113483) of how to implement these kinds of constraints using triggers.

Comment: doesnt look like it has shorten or optimised the query as such but nice try though

Comment: I like that! Thank you.

Comment: This does not guarantee that all six positions have players.  It is curious that it is accepted.

Comment: Good point! Might have accepted too early. Will see in the next few days when actually implementing the query.

Comment: Good point! Sorry I missed that in the initial scoping (I missed it because I think it's technically allowed in the question's DDL and there wasn't a sample with that being not okay, but I see it in the text now!). I updated the answer with a cross reference on how you *could* handle it if you wanted to go with a normalized table and still ensure all six rows.

Answer (score 1):

To shorten the query length use `NOT IN`

```
    CONSTRAINT no_duplicate_players
    CHECK (pos_1 NOT IN(pos_2,pos_3,pos_4,pos_5)) -- n --similar for each column
```

or the better way would be each `pos1..n` be all foreign keys ( similar to a fact table in a datawarehouse schema)
such that these will refer your main table.

Answer (score 1):

Impaler has the right idea, but you also want to guarantee that all six positions have players.  For that, you need `NOT NULL` constraints as well:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS lineup (
  match_id    INTEGER REFERENCES matches,
  pos_1       INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES players,
  pos_2       INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES players,
  pos_3       INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES players,
  pos_4       INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES players,
  pos_5       INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES players,
  pos_6       INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES players,
  constraint chk_linup_pos
    check (pos_2 not in (pos_1) and
           pos_3 not in (pos_1, pos_2) and
           pos_4 not in (pos_1, pos_2, pos_3) and
           pos_5 not in (pos_1, pos_2, pos_3, pos_4) and
           pos_6 not in (pos_1, pos_2, pos_3, pos_4, pos_5) 
          );
);
```

Although you can normalize the data structure, it is really, really hard to have a fixed constraint such as "all six positions must be filled" when the values span multiple rows.  If you really want to implement that, then this structure is probably the simplest mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

A simple constraint will do:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS lineup (
  match_id    INTEGER REFERENCES matches,
  pos_1       INTEGER REFERENCES players,
  pos_2       INTEGER REFERENCES players,
  pos_3       INTEGER REFERENCES players,
  pos_4       INTEGER REFERENCES players,
  pos_5       INTEGER REFERENCES players,
  pos_6       INTEGER REFERENCES players,
  constraint chk1
    check (pos_1 <> pos_2
       and pos_1 <> pos_3
       and pos_1 <> pos_4
       and pos_1 <> pos_5
       and pos_1 <> pos_6
       and pos_2 <> pos_3
       and pos_2 <> pos_4
       and pos_2 <> pos_5
       and pos_2 <> pos_6
       and pos_3 <> pos_4
       and pos_3 <> pos_5
       and pos_3 <> pos_6
       and pos_4 <> pos_5
       and pos_4 <> pos_6
       and pos_5 <> pos_6             
    )
);
```